# Is the a way to validate object references within JSON with JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Let's take a simple example when we define objects and use them separately within JSON. For instance, we define several addresses and use them to define several routes:

```
{
    "points": [
        {
            "Name": "p1",
            "Street": "street1",
            "House": 11,
            "Ap": 111
        },
        {
            "Name": "p2",
            "Street": "street2",
            "House": 22,
            "Ap": 222
        },
        {
            "Name": "p3",
            "Street": "street3",
            "House": 33,
            "Ap": 333
        },
        {
            "Name": "p4",
            "Street": "street4",
            "House": 44,
            "Ap": 444
        },
        {
            "Name": "p5",
            "Street": "street5",
            "House": 55,
            "Ap": 555
        }

    ],
    "routes": [
        [
            "p1",
            "p2",
            "p3",
            "p4"
        ],
        [
            "p3",
            "p2",
            "p1"            
        ],
        [
            "p4",
            "p2",
            "p3",
            "p1"
        ]
    ]
}
```

What would be a right way, if any, to validate with JSON schema, that all routes refer to defined addresses? Sorry if my question is too newbie.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi Oleg. This is an interesting case because you are representing a graph structure in JSON. I don't think it is possible to validate the references from routes to points (assuming you can have an arbitrary number of points). You can define a regex but of course this only catches some errors.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You must do this in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use JSON Schema to validate relational data represented in JSON has referencial integrity.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I got the same answer. Actually I've found some discussions dated 2016 regarding introduction of '$data' keyword for that purpose, but apparently it wasn't included in standard.

Comment: Last year we release JSON Schema draft `2019-09`. We introduced the concept of "vocabularies", which may later lead to being able to do what you're asking, or something like $data, but not as of now.